# Number of rows in a datetime index sampled by day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to count the number of rows of the index in Data frame X and then group by day, I am trying to get something as Data frame Y showing 11 rows on 7/10/2020 and 12 rows in 7/11/2020

[image: 1]

Comment: ``df.groupby(df.index.date).size().reset_index(name='Index rows')``

Answer (score 0):

sample data frame:

```
    date
0   1986-04-01
1   1963-02-22
2   1963-02-22
3   1963-02-22
4   1963-02-22
5   1963-02-22
6   1978-05-12
7   1985-09-17
8   1985-03-17
9   1962-02-11
10  1984-09-19
11  1957-03-30
12  1984-09-19
13  1957-03-30
14  1984-09-19
15  1957-03-30
16  1977-08-23
17  1986-01-13
```

code :

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
```

output:

```
date
1957-03-30    3
1962-02-11    1
1963-02-22    5
1977-08-23    1
1978-05-12    1
1984-09-19    3
1985-03-17    1
1985-09-17    1
1986-01-13    1
1986-04-01    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nope this is not what OP want's, here it's not a column instead datetimeindex & its not just date its ``date-time``